# In which case does the notion api return a Pagination of Pages?

Tags: notion-api, notion

In the API documentation, various pagination types are listed, including

```
"block," "comment," "database," "page," "page_or_database," "property_item," and "user."
```

However, I am uncertain about which endpoint specifically returns a pagination of `"pages."` Despite searching the documentation, I couldn't find a conclusive answer.

During experimentation with dummy data, specifically a list comprised solely of pages, I observed that the pagination type remained `"pages_or_databases,"` contrary to my expectations of it being `"page."`